# Error: librocksdbjni6770528225908825804.dll whil joining 2 streams or while creating KTable in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Creating KStream from a topic and able to get data out of it. Trying to join 2 streams generated from different topics to see the following error. I'm getting this error 1) while trying to create KTable from topic or stream. 2) while performing the join on two streams.

```
Exception in thread "conferences-16397ea6-09e3-4e52-b5dc-2cdf0c830857-StreamThread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\srikanth\AppData\Local\Temp\2\librocksdbjni6770528225908825804.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
    at org.rocksdb.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:25)
```

Googled and added the following dependency:
    `compile group: 'org.rocksdb', name: 'rocksdbjni', version: '5.11.3'` but couldn't come over it. 
Kafka version: `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:4.1.0` 
Kafka Stream dependency version: `compile('org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:1.0.1')`
Tried with `1.0.0` and `1.1.0` as well. Few blogs says, its bug in version, but I have tried all 3 versions and the result is saame. Help me resolve this.

Comment: There are some knows issue with Kafka Streams on WindowsOS, or to be more precise RocksDB issues. Kafka Streams uses RockDB but RocksDB binaries are not available for all WindowsOS versions. It's best to run Kafka Streams in an Linux environment or try out a different WindowsOS version.

Comment: As long as you don't use any stateful operators, Kafka Streams will just work on WindowsOS, because it does not use RocksDB for this case. You can also replace RocksDB with an in-memory store (shipped with Kafka Streams) as long as you don't do windowed aggregations/joins (currently, there is no in-memory window store available out-of-the box)